# Template for a "About" dialog for an Elementary OS application

Tags: applications, programming, vala

I have developed an application for elementary which is a Network Utility. The details of the Nutty application can be found here at launchpad:
https://launchpad.net/nutty

In response to a bug report, I'm trying to build an About page for the app. I'm looking for some sample code for the template used by the About dialog of elementary OS apps like Files, Scratch, etc.

Rather than create my own layout, it will be good if I can keep the About dialog in the same format as other elementary OS apps. Can someone point me at some relevant code.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Nutty is currently broken (segmentation fault). Can you fix it

Comment: Can you try and delete all files in ~/.config/nutty and retry. Hope you have got the latest 0.7 version of Nutty from ppa:bablu-boy/nutty.0.1. Let me know the steps to recreate the issue if the problem re-occurs after cleaning the config files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for Granite.Widgets.AboutDialog.

You can find everything about it here : [Valadoc Granite.Widgets.AboutDialog](http://valadoc.org/#!api=granite/Granite.Widgets.AboutDialog)

If you can't recognize a widget in a particular application, try using the new GTK+ Inspector, its really handy in situations like this.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer. I was indeed looking for the About Dialog. Should be able to find my way from here. Thanks again!